# PowerShell - Csv : foreach with conditions?

Tags: powershell

I have to import a csv file, and I want to put a condition directly in the foreach. I mean :

To read the csv, i do (yes my delimiter is \ ) :

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Delimiter \ -Path $mypath -Header 'column1', 'column2', 'column3'
```

Then i do :

```
foreach($line in $csv)
{
#Actions
}
```

What i would like to do, but I din't know if it's possible :

```
for($i =1; $i -lt $myarray.Length; $i++)
{
   foreach($line in $csv) | Where $line.column2 -eq $myarray[$i]
   {
      #Actions only if $line.column2 is equal to $myarray[$i]
   }
}
```

So i got an array, with names inside. And I want to do #Actions, only if a column in the csv, match to the information in my array. If not, I want to change of $line in $csv.

The idea i wrote looks so heavy, and I think there is a better and faster (harder and stronger #DaftPunk) way to do this.

If someone has already use this before, let me know :)

Thanks in advance,

Nico.

P.S : I apologize for my english ;)

EDIT : I've just realized that i can do a if condition :

```
for($i =1; $i -lt $myarray.Length; $i++)
{
   foreach($line in $csv)
   {
      if($line.column2 -eq $myarray[$i]
      {
         #Actions
      }
   }
}
```

But i still think that a : | Where #Conditions, is better ...

And if someone is able to add : loop, foreach, condition / as tags, would be cool, because i can't do it with my low reputation :(